# Singly Linked Lists: How to add the head

Tags: java

I have an assignment to implement a singly linked list. I am trying to figure out how to get the head but I end up getting stack overflow errors or null pointer errors. Could someone help me. I have displayed the relevant pieces of code:

```
public class Llist {

    private Object data;
    private Llist next;
    private Llist head = new Llist(null, null);

    public Llist(Object d) {
        this(d, null);
    }

    public Llist(Object d, Llist n) {
        data = d;
        next = n;
    }
```

I have a method to add a node, it will check whether or not there is a head, if there isnt then the new node is the head:

```
public static Llist add(Llist l, Object d) {
    Llist n = new Llist(d,l);
    if(l.head == null) {
        l.head = n;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Currently I get a stack overflow error... but if I remove the line of setting the head to null in the 2

Comment: How are you calling `add`?

Comment: It would be better to grab an Algorithm and Data Structures book from [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/1065197) or another of your favorite flavor and practice. By the way, your `add` method shouldn't be `static`.

Comment: I call add in the main method on a new Llist I made.

Comment: like this:
Llist l = null;
l.add(l, 6);
}

Comment: `Llist l = null` means that you do not have a `Llist` yet, and calling `l.add()` won't work.

Comment: ok I do: 
Llist l = new Llist(6);
add.(l, 6);

I still get the stack overflow error..

Answer (score 1):

Your linked list isn't setup properly at all.  A linked list should only have a reference to the head node, and the head node should hold a reference to the next node. It should look more like:

```
public class Llist {

    private Object data;
    private Llist next;

    public Llist(Object d) {
        this(d, null);
    }

    public Llist(Object d, Llist n) {
        data = d;
        next = n;
    }
```

In which case you should always hold a copy of the head node, otherwise you lose the whole list, because your list and nodes are the same type in this implementation.

A better implementation would have a separate Node class.  Something like:

```
public class Llist {
    private Node head;

    public Llist(Object o) {
        head = new Node(o);
    }

    public void add(Object o){
        curr = head;
        while(curr != null){
             curr = curr.next;
        }
        curr.next = new Node(o)
    }

public class Node{
    Object data;
    Node next;

    public Node(Object o){
        data = o;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that is a better implemenation but the lecturer has said that you cannot change the given code...

Answer (score 0):

The reason for Stackoverflow error is you are stuck in a infinite recursion

```
public static Llist add(Llist l, Object d) {
    Llist n = new Llist(d,l);
```

Here you create a **object n** which has **head object** of type Llist, the head object inturn has another head object of type Llist

So, the program keeps on allocating memory space `n->head->head->head->...` and so on until it reaches its limit

Comment: so to stop this recursion it would mean I would have to remove the field head? But if I do that how would I be able to assign a head?

Comment: Wait. Didn't I make the head object to be null, how is the recursion possible?

Comment: @miniJavaLearner : no you didn't you just assigned the value of next and data to be null. but, you are still creating the head object.Also, there is no need to keep a head object in the Class. just keep a reference of Llist named head